# How do I save user's input in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I made a simple App that collects users' input and arrane it as list, but how do I save it.
I want to be save users' input, so whenever the app is launched, the previous input is available. I think with has something to do with `kivy.json`, or something like that(I don't really know), but I don't know how to implement it.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

here is my main.py file.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, IconLeftWidget
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (300, 530)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Gray'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '200'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

    def add_item(self, text):
        new_list_item = OneLineIconListItem(text=text)
        new_list_item.add_widget(
            IconLeftWidget(icon="pin")
        )
        self.root.ids.listcontainer.add_widget(new_list_item)
        self.root.ids.listinput.text = ''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

And here's my .kv file

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: box
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'MyApp'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}

    MDTextField:
        id: listinput
        hint_text: 'Add Item'
        mode: 'rectangle'
        size_hint_x: .9
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        text_validate_unfocus: False
        on_text_validate: app.add_item(listinput.text)

    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True

            MDList:
                id: listcontainer
```

I would really appreciate any help, Thanks a lot in advance, for your help.

Comment: you should save the data to local file inside on_stop method and load the  data in on_start data

Comment: Thanks @HussamF.Alkdary I really your contribution, I am not really familiar with it, I would really appreciate if you could show me how the code will lool like. Thank you for help.